# GridLayout - how to set a different column size for bottom row?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

How can I make a GridLayout that has several rows with 2 columns in each, where the left column is shorter than the right except the bottom row, where the 2 columns need to be equal widths? [image: This is what I'm aiming for.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="5"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="Spinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:text="Spinner" />
</android.widget.GridLayout>
```

No matter what I try, the best I can end up with is something like this: [image: this.] 
Can this work with a GridLayout or will I need to use a different layout?